# Unable to start fragment Activity intent from service when Main Activity isn't already running

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have a service in the background that starts on phone boot, and displays a dialog (polling a server) that can being you to a fragmentActivity class created by the main activity if the user chooses to.

The problem is, on boot, the service is running but main activity isn't, so when I launch the intent to the fragment, it crashes due to the main activity not being loaded.

What is the right way of loading the main activity in order for me to load the fragment?

I could load it on boot and bring it to background but that looks tacky with the app loading at boot and closing.

Or I could call an intent to call the main activity before the fragment, but that also looks tacky because I need to do a Thread.sleep() to make sure the main activity finished loading before loading the fragment.

I don't think I can extend broadcast receiver to not do the Thread.sleep(), because all my activities are already extended to something else (e.g. Service, Activity)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch the intent for the activity instead of the Fragment.

Comment: that works, call the activity first and then have the activity launch the fragment after activity is launched